# How to inline option tags in select and divide them using optgroup?

Tags: html, css

The actual problem is to use option tag in select block in horizontal way and divide option values using optgroup.

So the expected result would be:

`Showing elements on the page 10 | 20 | 30`,  where 10,20,30 are selectable and table will show selected amount of elements

The solution I came to is:

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select size="3">
       <optgroup label="|">
           <option value="10">10</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="|">
           <option value="20">20</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="|">
           <option value="30">30</option>
       </optgroup>
   </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.styled-select {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:30px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:25px;
}

.styled-select select {
  margin: -1px -20px -5px -5px;

}

optgroup {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:32px;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

optgroup:nth-child(1) {
  visibility:hidden;
}

.styled-select select option{
  visibility:visible;
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:15px;
  margin-left:12px !important;
  padding-top:-10px !important;
  margin-top:-16px !important;
  text-align: center;

}

.styled-select select option::before{
  content: none;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Result you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/834gwtz7/4/

If you have any suggestions, how to do it in more elegant way, please help!

Comment: UPD: I am tied to using select with option, because i am using DataTables to display elements. And select is used to set the max number of elements to show per page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as a "dirty" solution, for those, who also has that kind of requirement and uses datatables, you can use solution from my question. I truly understand that it is not such elegant way to do it, so suggestions are welcome =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I followed what you wanted to do, but maybe something more simple like this work the same?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
#styled-select select optgroup {
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<div id="styled-select">
   <select size="3">
       <optgroup label="option1">
           <option value="10">10</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="option2">
           <option value="20">20</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="option3">
           <option value="30">30</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
       </optgroup>
   </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it's not similar to my result.. Please see the link attached in the question https://jsfiddle.net/834gwtz7/4/